# embeddedTomcatconfiguration replace by httpConfiguration

Tags: azure, ssl, gradle, java-8, azure-pipelines

After move web app to bee build by Azure Pipeline i get problem with open SSL port. When i deploy application built by local machine everything is fine, by when i try install new version build by azure in start log i see...

(left - local machine, right - azure pipeline)

[image]

It seems he is replace instance of singleton bean 'embeddedTomcatConfiguration' by 'httpConfiguration' and this why ssl won't open. Before this line all logs is the same.

Bellow logs with information witch port are open.

**Local version:**- open port **8433** http, **6060** http and **8444** https

[image]

**Azure version**:- only port **8433** http and **6060** http

[image]

App is spring web app. Bellow comparison of version use to build.

**Local version:**

- gradleVersion: 4.8.1
- createdBy: 1.8.0_302 (Temurin 25.302-b08)

**Azure:**

- gradleVersion: 4.8.1
- createdBy: 1.8.0_292 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.292-b10)

Additional information, application use ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]

I would be very grateful for your help in solving the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually http protocol over TLS/SSL uses 443/tcp  ports, Also when it is working fine locally, it should work as expected after the deployment. Looks like we are missing few configurations for webapps.

Below are few important key aspects which should be looked into:

Deployment steps of a webapp.

[image]

Refer to the [blog](https://iamvickyav.medium.com/azure-devops-ci-cd-deploying-war-file-into-tomcat-running-in-azure-app-service-b173e89389ec) to understand about running tomcat in App Service and automating it with pipeline in azure.

If your application will be visible on a custom domain, you'll need to map your web application to it. Then, you'll need to [bind the SSL certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings) for that domain to your App Service Web App

Configuring [custom tls/ssl in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/migration/migrate-tomcat-to-tomcat-app-service#configure-custom-domain-and-ssl)

Azure App Service provides a highly scalable, self-patching web hosting service. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/migration/migrate-tomcat-to-tomcat-app-service#configure-custom-domain-and-ssl) shows you how to create, upload, or import a private certificate or a public certificate into App Service.

Also, to create custom TLS/SSL bindings or enable client certificates for your App Service app, your App Service plan must be in the Basic, Standard, Premium, or Isolated tier.